Why would square-tessellated barriers be the best against slashing attacks?
I have mages who can conjure hard, flat, glass-like barriers that can be tessellated with triangles, hexagons, or squares. Hexagon-tessellated barriers(inspired by the geodesic dome) are for blunt, slamming forces that spread stress evenly throughout the whole barrier like war hammers. Triangle-tessellated barriers are for fast, piercing attacks that concentrate the force in a small point like arrows or bullets since triangles are apparently the strongest of the shape, perfect for enduring all-or-nothing attacks meant to quickly assassinate.
My problem here are square-tessellated barriers. They're supposed to be best at enduring against slashing attacks that impart force in a straight line horizontally, vertically, or diagonally. I can't really find anything to use as justification. So my question is: Why would square-tessellated barriers be the best against slashing forces?

They're magic barriers, why is there a need for explanation beyond that?

They probably wouldn't if you are justifying hexagons and triangles. Hexagons are just joined up triangles. Triangles are the strongest shape. If anything the best shape against both piercing and slashing would be a dome which would deflect impacts

No reason at all. What is best against slamming, punching, slashing forces and whatever else is the spherical barrier, not the flat one. Then, it is easier to tessellate a dome with shapes that look all the same from afar if said shapes are triangular, than if they are square.

Why would it matter how the magic manifests itself? It's presumably built to do a thing and does the thing because that's why this magic effect exists. Just because it manifests in squares, hexagons, yellow, or red, or whatever doesn't seems relevant to why it does the thing it was supposed to do.

It would help if you could explain how the shape of the tesserae signals to your audience (not sure if it would help you with the -1's; can't harm, though). Are they a visual concept, for e. g. a comic strip, video game?  If so, I would suggest triangles are connoted with rigidity, hexagons with parsimony, lightweightness and squares with flexibility. If not,... well, your call.

Triangular elements are rigid (without the need for the vertex joints to be rigid) against forces acting in the plane of the triangle. The barriers in the question are most likely supposed to work against forces perpendicular to the plane of the triangles.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not a worldbuilding quesiton, it's a "please crowbar science into my already built world" question. You've already done the worldbuilding, now you're looking for what, at best, is a story rationale for you choice. For the record, if you throw science to the wind, it makes more logical sense to assign your attack types based on the number of verticies that come together. ... (*Continued*)

... Triangles have 6, squares 4 and polys 3. So blunt for triangles, slash for squares and poly for piercing.

Squares create flat planes to deflect blades
For mystical reasons, manipulating the topological surface of a tessellating barrier creates strength:

At edges proportional to the number of edges in their constituent polygons,
At vertices proportional to the number of vertices in their constituent polygons,
And in the interior inversely proportional to the sum of both.

Therefore,

Triangles are used for point-attacks, because a mesh of triangles is most resistant to sustain a hit to the interior, and prevent an arrow or projectile from simply punching through the shield.
Squares are used for slashing attacks, because they can present a balance of point/edge strength and interior strength, and can be shaped into a wedge to deflect slashes,
Hexagons are used against blunt force attacks, because they sacrifice strength in their interior for how strongly they hold together, preventing the shield from being torn apart.




Credit to Kirill Kolchenko at the Noun Project for image of man.

At first I really liked the foldability of squares, but after thinking about it a bit more, I realized that you can also fold a triangular tessellation, and that foldability is actually only going to be more important for deflecting a piercing attack.  A piercing weapon has to thrust meaning it will hit a folded shield at an angle deflecting it, but slashing or bludgeoning weapons are swung meaning that they are more likely to deflect off of a flat shield than a wedge shaped one.

@Nosajimiki My rationale is that while a triangle tesselation can also be folded, because triangles are weaker at join points, a slash weapon, with its broader leading edge, is more likely to strike and break through one of those weak points. The squares are stronger at join points, so they are more likely to deflect the blow.

@Nosajimiki As for projectiles, the chance of them hitting an 'edge' rather than an 'interior' is very small, since they're a point impact, so you want the shape with the greatest interior strength (the triangle.)

There is an inverse relationship between the vertex to polygon ratio and the hardness of the polygons
How well any material blocks any one of the aforementioned attacks have a lot more to do with how hard/tough/compressible the material is than its exact shape.  In general, a hard crystalline solid will do the best job of blocking a piercing attack, a semi-hard solid does the best against a slashing attack, and a flexible, compressible material will do more to absorb a bludgeoning impact.  So, there is something about mage-shield weaving where the more vertices you have per polygon, the softer and less rigid the shield is.
So the hex shield when hit will have a lot of give like a giant trampoline allowing it to slow a heavy attack, but is too soft allowing sharp weapons to pierce or cut through it. A triangle shield is very rigid like ceramic coffee cup such that a hammer or sword will shatter it, but a piercing attack is unable to bite into it forcing it to glance off. Lastly, your square shield is somewhere in between having s quality similar to wood.  It's not quite soft enough to stop a hammer or hard enough to keep a spear from biting in, but a slashing weapon which can shatter triangles or cut through hexes is not good enough at either to overcome the middle-ground square woven mage-shield.

... that is absolutely wild, I swear I wrote my answer without even seeing this one. Truly, great minds think alike!

@DanielB It's fine, Your answer also adds a key point about the foldability of squares adding a 3rd aspect to the polygonal shapes that goes beyond a simple compromise of hardness and toughness; so, while it is similar, it definitely builds more on the idea making it IMO the better overall answer.

On second thought... while the folding thing is a key difference between our answers, I don't think it actually makes sense for why a square grid would do better against slashing specifically.

The underlayer of the armor is a tough woven textile.  It is at 45 degrees to the outer squares, so that a sword cuts through all the individual fibers running in any direction.  If the sword could slice along the grain of the fabric, it would only need to cut through half as many fibers.  The squares are also designed to catch knives into the grooves, dull them, and twist them a little sideways (using "rifling" on the edge of each square).  While it appears that cutting between the squares avoids the rigid protection of the armor, there are heavy, sturdy links between the squares down even below the textile layer, as a final line of defense targeted specifically to these redirected sword strikes.

The cube give, rotate and clamp at the same time, similar to a fractal vise.
https://www.metmo.co.uk/blogs/news/getting-to-grips-with-the-fractal-vise
The more power you put into it, the tighter it grips. Your weapon is now part of the barrier.
Bonus points if the barrier csn form a golemn, reusing your weapons against you.

Why wouldn't this work against any weapon? Especially piercing - sounds like an excellent way to also deal with spears. Should also work against blunt weapons. Why have any other types of barriers at all?

Because once it eats a swoard- it becomes stuck, stable and brittle?

I don't know how to answer that question. I don't know how it answers mine. Can you state plainly why would what you suggest work well against slashing but not piercing nor blunt.
